# MySQL MONTH returns wrong results

Tags: mysql

The following query didn't return correct results, because it returns results from "September" month but i need to get results from given month "August".

Is there something wrong in my query?

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE  YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_date)) = '2012'  AND 
       MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_date)) = '08' 
order by UNIX_date DESC
```

EDIT:

results that returned were like that:

```
 post_id    user_id     UNIX_date
 95319       12         1346475459
 97370        5         1346474849
 83527       25         1346474631
 83526       51         1346473357
 85929       12         1346471009
 26677       29         1346462100
 26839       12         1346432911
 85927       12         1346411636
```

Comment: Check the current server time using `SELECT NOW() FROM table`

Comment: there are 7 hours different between my local time and server time!

Answer (score 0):

The month should not have a leading `0`. So try `8` instead of `08`.
You could also post a line of what is being returned so we can see how UNIX_date looks like.

reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month

Comment: Did you try to use 8 instead of 08 in your check?

Comment: is there such an alternative way? like using `between` and how?

Comment: Well you could check if `FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_date) >= '2012-08-01 00:00:00' and FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_date) <= '2012-08-31 23:59:59'` or something similar. But, without testing, it feels like your approach should work.. .hmmm

Comment: also didn't work it has showed results from "September month"!! i checked my server time and i found that there are 7 hours different between my local time and server time, does this has any efficient!?

Comment: The sql server works on the time of your server so shouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month, the `DAY`, `MONTH` and `YEAR` functions returns integer, thus values 1-12 (or zero) for the `MONTH`.